# Detect MS Windows

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

#### Challenge

Create a program that returns a truthy value when run on Microsoft Windows (for simplicity we'll stick with Windows 7, 8.1 and 10) and a falsey value when run on any other operating system (OSX, FreeBSD, Linux).

#### Rules

- Code that fails to run/compile on a platform doesn't count as a falsey value.

#### Winning criteria

I'm labelling this as [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest score wins, but I'm also very interested in seeing creative solutions to this problem.

Comment: Can the programs output by exit code? ([normally allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5330/60919))

Comment: I'm gonna say yes @FlipTack

Comment: Can you give a definite list of which operating systems this needs to work on?

Comment: is `True␤` and `False␤` valid outputs?

Comment: What should the result be under Windows RT?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66695/an-executable-script-file-that-runs-on-posix-and-windows)

Comment: You may want to specify a few specific non-Windows systems that must be supported. There's some debates in comments about things like DOS and OS2.

Comment: We probably need a consensus about what counts as truthy and falsey for exit codes; the normal convention is 0 for true and anything else for false, but many answers are treating it as the opposite, and the "if statement" definition doesn't obviously apply.

Comment: Such discrimination... Windows? *Shudder* :)

Comment: **English: 1 thought**: Are you looking at a Blue Screen Of Death?

Comment: WIN32 macros. Its *magic!*

Comment: I wonder if ReactOS gives false positives from some of these answers

Comment: This isn't nearly short enough to be competitive, but it certainly uses a unique and imo baffling approach: NodeJS, 43 bytes `_=>new Promise(r=>require("fs").fstat(0,r))`.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

## Vim, 2 bytes

```
<C-a>1
```

On Windows, `<C-a>` (ctrl+a) is mapped by default to `Select All`.  If you type a `1` in select mode in Windows, it replaces the selection with what you typed (1) leaving a 1 in the buffer.

On other operating systems, `<C-a>` by default is mapped to `Increment number`.  Because there's no number to increment, it's a no-op, and then the 1 increases the count but in terms of the buffer is a no-op.

1 is truthy in Vim, and an empty string is falsy

Comment: Looks like 3 keystrokes. Ctrl+a+1

Comment: I think per this meta post http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8995/how-should-vim-answers-be-scored Vim answers are generally scored without the modifiers (especially given that the first answer on the post uses <ctrl+a> as an example for 1 byte)

Comment: @Pavel it's `Ctrl + a`, `1`. If it were `Ctrl + a + 1` it'd be counted as 1 keystroke.

Comment: Beautiful, I love this answer!

Comment: That's rather elegant, I like it.

Answer (score 108):

## MATLAB, 4 bytes

```
ispc
```

From the [documentation](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ispc.html):

> `tf = ispc` returns logical 1 (true) if the version of MATLAB® software is for the Microsoft® Windows® platform. Otherwise, it returns logical 0 (false).

There are also the functions [`ismac`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismac.html) and [`isunix`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isunix.html). <s>I'll leave it to the reader to figure out what those functions do.</s> [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego) kindly asked for diagrams explaining `ismac` and `isunix` so I've tried to illustrate it here:

[image]

It was not asked for a diagram of `ispc` but I can reveal that the behaviour is pretty similar, except substitute `OSX` and `Unix` with `Windows`.

---

**Second approach:**

Here's a second approach with [`getenv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getenv.html) using 23 bytes that should be bullet proof, unless there's another operating system starting with `W`:

```
x=getenv('OS');x(1)==87
```

> `getenv 'name'` searches the *underlying operating system environment
>   list* for text of the form `name=value`, where `name` is the input
>   character vector. If found, MATLAB® returns the character vector
>   value. If the specified name cannot be found, an empty matrix is
>   returned.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51632/discussion-on-answer-by-stewie-griffin-detect-ms-windows).

Answer (score 56):

## [Python 2.7.10](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
import os
0/('['>os.sep)
```

Thanks to FlipTack for 3 bytes

This program takes advantage of the fact that Windows is the only OS to use `\` as a path separator. Normally this is frustrating and bad, but for once it is actually an advantage. On Windows, `'['>os.sep` is false, and thus `0/0` is computed, causing a `ZeroDivisionError` and exiting with a non-zero exit code. On non-Windows platforms, `'['>os.sep` is true, making the expression `0/1`, which does nothing, and the program exits with exit code 0.

Comment: DOS also uses a backslash as the path separator and it has at least one Python 2 implementation.

Comment: @isanae I've edited the title to specify Python 2.7 - the only Python 2 implementation on DOS is an archaic, buggy 2.4.2

Comment: OS/2 also uses a backslash and has a Python 2.7 implementation ;)

Comment: @isanae The only Python 2 port I see for OS/2 is 2.4.4: https://www.python.org/download/other/

Comment: [This port](http://os2ports.smedley.id.au/index.php?page=python) is 2.7.5.

Comment: @isanae There, I specified 2.7.10. Good luck finding a port of that.

Comment: apparently it only needs to give correct results on 3 recent windows versions and presumably similarly recent versios of the three other systems listed, OS2 and DOS don't matter,

Comment: I love that 'non-zero exit code' --> truthy value

Comment: @Luigi Whoops, I said it backwards. It is a bit odd, honestly, that `0` is truthy in shell contexts, but falsey basically everywhere else. The `>` could be swapped for a `<`, and then it will exit with `0` on Windows and non-zero elsewhere.

Comment: Would  doing `os.sep=="\\"` be ok ?  With import, that line adds up to 19 bytes. What do you guys think ?

Comment: @Serg That's a snippet, not a function or full program.

Comment: @Mego   I'm not saying to use that line alone, of course it needs import.

Comment: @Serg That's not the problem. It doesn't utilize one of the acceptable I/O methods. The program I have, for example, outputs via exit code. Previously, I used STDOUT for output.

Comment: @Mego ah, I see what you mean

Comment: Interesting solution. So all we need is a language which is only implemented for Windows, and then return true.

Answer (score 47):

### <s>x86 Assembly, 7 bytes</s> (Inspired by [Runemoro's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106180/63767))

```
31 DB 89 D8 40 CD 80
```

Or

```
xor ebx, ebx 
mov eax, ebx
inc eax
int 0x80
```

### Description

First of all, we'll set `eax` to `1` (the system call number for `exit(int val)` for `Linux`, `FreeBSD` and `OSX`).
Then, we'll call the interrupt gate `0x80` which is the system call gate for `Linux`, `FreeBSD` and `OSX`. That would cause the program to exit with status of `ebx` which is `0` (`false`).

On Windows `int 0x80` is an invalid gate (It uses `2e` as a syscall gate) and would crash the program, causing it to end with a positive exit code (`true`).

**Edit:** Would not work on `OSX` since it has a different argument-passing convention on 32 bit (by the stack).

### References and further reading

- [`FreeBSD - System Calls`](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html): Information about system calls in `FreeBSD`.
- [`System calls in the Linux kernel. Part 2.`](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/syscall-2.html):  A great article about Linux's system calls.
- [`Linux Syscall Reference`](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/): a system call numbers reference for `Linux`.
- [`Windows Syscall Shellcode`](https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-syscall-shellcode) : An article about directly calling system calls in `windows` from assembly.
- [`Making system calls from Assembly in Mac OS X`](https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/): An article about system calls on `OSX`.

Comment: That's brilliant!

Comment: Why does the crash cases a truthy value? Is it because EAX (typically the return value) is 1? Also, is EAX guaranteed to be 0 at program start? Or do you need `xor eax, eax` in there?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: OS-detected crashes (on the operating systems typically used with x86) never leave an exit code of 0, because that's reserved for successful termination. (Normally the exit code is some wonky value that the OS reserves specifically for this circumstance.) However, I'm not sure it makes sense to count 0 as falsey and 1 as truthy in program exit codes, given that the normal convention is the exact opposite (with 0 being the only truthy vaue, e.g. the standard UNIX/Linux/POSIX program `false` exits with code 1 whilst `true` exits with code 0).

Comment: @ais523 The relevant [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106079/detect-ms-windows) on the _Interpretation of Truthy/Falsey_ post on meta also states

that 0 is truthy and nonzero is falsy.

Comment: This answer implicitly assumes that registers `eax` and `ebx` are cleared to zero on program start (on non-Windows), which is *not* guaranteed if I remember correctly.  It also explicitly assumes that the syscall argument-passing convention for Linux matches that for FreeBSD and OSX, which would be very surprising indeed.

Comment: @zwol You're right about the `eax` and `ebx`. I'll update the answer. The argument-passing  convention is the same for `Linux` and `FreeBSD`  (with linux emulation). However, I could not verify about `OSX`.  I will fix these problems, thank you for the corrections.

Comment: Why not just `mov eax, 1` to get rid of the `inc` call?

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc Good question. `mov eax, 1` would be translated to `\xB8\x01\x00\x00\x00`, which is a lot longer that just moving register and calling `inc`.

Answer (score 29):

## PHP, 22 bytes

```
`<?=PATH_SEPARATOR>":";`
```

prints `1` if the path separator is semicolon (colon or empty for all other OSs except for DOS and OS/2), else nothing.

**also 22 bytes**, but not that safe:

```
<?=strpos(__FILE__,92);
```

prints a positive integer if the file path contains a backslash; else nothing.
A safe alternative with **27 bytes**: `<?=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR>"/";` prints `1` or nothing.

**A strange find**: `<?=__FILE__[1]==":";` (**20 bytes**) should be, not safe either, but ok.
But although `__FILE__` pretends to be a string (I tried `var_dump` and `gettype`), indexing it throws an error, unless you copy it somewhere else (concatenation also works) or use it as a function parameter.

Edit:
`<?=(__FILE__)[1]==":";` (also **22 bytes**) works in PHP 7; but that´s because the parentheses copy the constant´s value to a temporary variable.

**27 bytes**: `<?=stripos(PHP_OS,win)===0;`
tests if predefined `PHP_OS` constant starts with `win` (case insensitive; Windows,WIN32,WINNT, but not CYGWIN or Darwin); prints `1` for Windows, else nothing.

**17/18 bytes**:

```
<?=strlen("
")-1;
```

prints `1` if it was stored with Windows linebreak (also on DOS, OS/2 and Atari TOS - although I doubt that anyone ever compiled PHP for TOS), else `0`.

You could also check the constant `PHP_EOL`.

**more options:**

`PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX` is `dll` on Windows, but not necessarily only there.
`php_uname()` returns info on the operating system and more; starts with `Windows` for Windows.
`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` will contain `Windows` when called in a browser on Windows.
`<?=defined(PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_BUILD);` (38 bytes) works in PHP>=5.3

**conclusion**

The only failsafe way to tell if it´s really Windows, not anything looking like it, seems to be a check on the OS name. For PHP: `php_os()` may be disabled for security reasons; but `PHP_OS` will probably always contain the desired info.

Comment: File names on *nix can contain backslashes, so this isn't really foolproof. The rules don't say it has to be foolproof, though, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Jordan: You´re right. I added that info to the description. Thanks.

Comment: An alternative: `<?=class_exists(COM);`. The class `COM` is only available under Windows, as far as I know. That should save you one byte.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel That's enough of a different answer for you to post it as such. (However, it may not be worth it to do so; this answer is very well written.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It isn't worth it. The answer would be pushed to oblivion. That's why I simply left the comment, instead of writting my own answer.

Comment: The `strlen` one won't tell you the OS you're using, only the OS the file was saved on, and even that isn't certain, because Windows editors can save in LF, and non-Windows editors can save in CRLF.

Answer (score 28):

## C, <s>44</s> <s>43</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

*Thanks to @Downgoat for a byte! <sup>crossed out 44 is still regular 44</sup>*
*Thanks to @Neil for two bytes!*

```c
f(){return
#ifdef WIN32
!
#endif
0;}
```

Comment: Originally I was going to suggest that you can save a bunch of bytes by moving the `0` out of the `ifdef` and changing the `1` to `!`, but I think `_WIN32+0` works even better still.

Comment: If c99 is OK you can change f to main and stick `return 1;` inside the ifdef and remove the else, since main without return in c99 must return 0.

Comment: That's a compiler directive. If it's compiled on a Windows system and run on a Linux system, for example, it will still return 1.

Comment: Do you need _ in WIN32? I never added it on my code

Comment: @Neil, "Code that fails to run/compile on a platform doesn't count as a falsey value.", it won't compile on a Linux/macOS/etc system ([TIO link, click debug](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@ZV6KQpqFZXZRaUlqUpxDu6WdsZF3LBRLOTczMA8oAZa1r//8HAA)).

Comment: @Mego ^ (i can't ping you both in a single comment)

Comment: @Downgoat `_WIN32` is a always defined by the compiler, while `WIN32` is set by some project templates in Visual Studio. `_WIN32` is more reliable.

Comment: @isanae in PPCG, portability isn't an issue. It count if it works in one implementation.

Comment: @betseg Ahh, I didn't think about that.

Comment: @betseg Sorry, I thought it would be empty or zero for some reason.

Comment: My comment about `!` still stands though, and saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @Neil oooh i got it now. Didn't understand when I first read it.

Comment: @MichealJohnson no. I can compile it on linux (using mingw32gcc msvc) snd get code that returns true when run on windows. I don't know of any windows-hosted linux compiler.  if you want to argue emulation layers like "wine" all the other answers probably suffer the same problem

Comment: @Jasen My point is, the return value is still set at compilation time not at execution time, so technically it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: all the other answers here are also using values set at compile time.

Comment: I'm not sure your count is accurate.  It looks like you've got 32 printable ASCII characters plus four line feeds.  A proper Windows text file would, of course, have CR+LF as line separators, so it would be 4 bytes more.  And a proper POSIX text file uses LF as line _terminators_ not _separators_, so you'd need one more byte for the last LF. ;-)

Comment: Not sure if WIN32 is just defined, but is defined to non-zero. If it's the later case, you can just say `#if WIN32`. On non-windows, since WIN32 is not defined, the preprocessor is required to treat it as 0.

Comment: -3 bytes if you replace the first line with `f(x){x=`.

Answer (score 16):

## Befunge-98, 7 bytes

```
6y2%!.@
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=NnkyJSEuQA&input=)

This works by querying the system path separator, which is `\` on Windows and `/` on other operating systems.

```
6y            System information query: #6 returns the path separator.
  2%          Test the low bit - this will be 1 for '/' and 0 for '\'.
    !         Not the value, so it becomes 0 for '/' and 1 for '\'.   
     .@       Output the result and exit.
```

Answer (score 15):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
$OperatingSystem=="Windows"&
```

Comment: What's the point in making it a function? You could remove the ampersand saving one byte, and the code would just directly evaluate whether it's executed is on a Windows-ish system.

Comment: @Ruslan All answers must be either full programs that print the result or callable functions. *If* this is declared a Mathematica notebook answer, then you might get away with calling it a full program, but if I invoke the thing from the command-line without the `&`, it won't print anything (and it's then also not a callable function, but merely a snippet/expression).

Comment: @MartinEnder Really no output? I get `Out[1]= False` output from this: `~/opt/Mathematica/11.0/Executables/math <<< '$OperatingSystem=="Windows"'`

Comment: @Ruslan I believe that also starts a notebook environment (just a command-line based one). What I mean by running a program from the command-line is using script mode.

Answer (score 13):

## Java 8, 33 bytes

*Special thanks to Olivier Grégoire for suggesting `separatorChar`, and Kritixi Lithos for -1 byte!*

This is a lambda expression which returns a boolean. This can be assigned to `Supplier<Boolean> f = ...;` and called with `f.get()`.

```java
()->java.io.File.separatorChar>90
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#NY2xCsIwFEXn5CvemAwGV6l2UHBz6igOz5rWJ2kSkpeCSL@9lqLThXsP59IQQ2J44YimMDnTFd8yBW@aEqMjmyoZy91RC63DnOGC5OEjAX5tZuQlxkAPGJZNNZzI99cbYOqzXlGAv2x/DMFZ9DV0cJiV3tTrMwVzJmdNthETckinJ6Z6t52FqJp3ZjuYUNjExczOq870lpXWlRRCiklOcv4C) - the server isn't windows, so this prints `false`. However, in my windows machine, the same code prints `true`.

What this code does is get the System's file seperator, and check whether its codepoint is larger than the character `[`. This true for Windows, as it uses `\` as the seperator - but every other OS uses `/`, which has a lower code in the ASCII table.

Comment: Won't this break on other OSes which start with W?

Comment: `()->java.io.File.separatorChar=='\\'` is only 36 bytes.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire nice one - and I can golf it to 34 using `()->java.io.File.separatorChar>'['`!

Comment: I think you can golf this using `>90` instead of `>'['` https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#LY0xC8IwEEbn5lfcmA4GVykWiuDm1FEcrjXWkzQJl2tBpL@9Buv68d77eocpwQXJf1SRBIV6IC@WH9hbaCCvAF0IzqIHnrwuK1UsShVx6lxm/8oc6A5jruhWmPxwvSEPqdz0BhCOsOpyV79wRkPBnMlZk2xERgl8eiLXh321Zrh9J7GjCZOYmEvivEbzO96el/UL

Comment: @KritixiLithos thanks, don't know why I didn't remember that...

Comment: @FlipTack I'm not very familiar with Java's lambdas, but don't you have to include the semicolon at the end?

Comment: @KritixiLithos This expression itself is a literal (function literals are allowed), just like `1`. When assigning it to a variable, the assignment is a statement and therefore requires the semicolon, like `int i = 1;` - but the lambda itself doesn't need the semicolon.

Comment: @Downgoat: Is there any other OS that starts with `W`?

Comment: @Titus WebOS, Whonix. Probably even more.

Comment: @Titus Wait, what about [WAITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAITS)?

Answer (score 12):

## R, 15 bytes

```
.Platform$O>"v"
```

Thanks to [plannapus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6741/plannapus) for the suggestion to use partial matching for list element extraction.

[.Platform](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Platform.html) is a list with some details of the platform under which R was built. There is an element `OS.type` (the only element with name starting with "O") which is character string, giving the Operating System (family) of the computer. One of `"unix"` or `"windows"`.

So `"unix"` is less then `"v"`, but `"windows"` is greater then `"v"`. Other valid 15 bytes answers are

```
.Platform$O>"V"
.Platform$O>"w"
.Platform$O>"W"
```

[R is being developed for the Unix-like, Windows and Mac families of operating systems](https://cloud.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-machines-does-R-run-on_003f). Other OS families are not supported.

Comment: there are platforms other than unix that aren't windows you know...

Comment: @muddyfish: .Platform[[1]] is defined as either "unix" or "windows" in R documentation. https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/base/man/Platform.Rd#L22

Comment: Sorry, that's ok then. The answer should probably be modified to include this fact to stop that being asked again

Answer (score 11):

## J, 7 bytes

```
6=9!:12
```

This is a verb (similar to a function) that uses the builtin foreign conjunction `9!:12` to acquire the system type where 5 is Unix and 6 is Windows32.

Comment: J Official documentation shows it returns this value for older Windows. "6 Windows32 (95/98/2000/NT)"  Does the documentation need to be updated?  What happens when it is 64 bit Windows? http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx009.htm

Comment: Tested on 64 bit Windows 7 and it returns a 6.  Documentation seems to be quite old.

Comment: @Keeta Yes I think it is old but it still returned a 6 for me on Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: 5 bytes: `IFWIN`
[source](https://github.com/jsoftware/jsource/blob/c14d740d291637804ba8649884412fd9206f9b87/jlibrary/system/main/stdlib.ijs#L14)

Answer (score 10):

### Perl, 11 bytes

```pl
print$^O=~MS
```

`^O` should be replaced by a literal Control-O.

Outputs `1` on windows, nothing on another OS.

Note that I'm not using `say` as it adds a trailing newline, which is truthy in Perl.

*-2 bytes thanks to primo. (and fixed potential issues)*
*-1 bytes thanks to ais523.*

Comment: AFAIR this won't work in Cygwin Perl.

Comment: This won't work in mingw Perl either. Perl treats those both as distinct operating systems from Windows, though (as they generally obey UNIX rather than Windows conventions), and it's not clear whether they should count for the purpose of the question. In other news, you can save a byte here by using a literal control-O character rather than `^O`.

Comment: @ais523 I edited that, thanks. As for Cygwin and Mingw, I'll delete the post if they should be considered as Windows, but as you say, it would make more sense to consider them like separate OS (or at least, like not-Windows OS).

Comment: Regex delimiters shouldn't be necessary `$^O=~W`, although, I would probably match against `MS`. Alternatively, you could also match `$^X=~':'`.

Comment: @primo right, thanks. I don't know any other OS with a `W` in it so I assumed checking for a `W` for fine.. any reasons why you suggest `MS` instead?

Comment: @Dada less likely to hit a false positive: Cygwin and Mingw have both already been mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

### x86 machine code, 9 bytes

```
40 39 04 24 75 02 CD 80 C3
```

Compiled from:

```
inc eax        ; set eax to 1
cmp [esp], eax ; check if [esp] == 1 (linux)
jne windows    ; jump over "int 0x80" if on windows
int 0x80       ; exit with exit code 0 (ebx)
windows:
ret            ; exit with exit code 1 (eax)
```

Comment: pure binary (COM) won't run on Windows or Linux so not sure if this is valid

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky There must be an interpreter for assembly.

Comment: You can make the code even shorter by leaving only `inc eax` and `int 0x80`, I think it should fail on windows and terminate the process.

Comment: @ShmuelH. We aren't allowed to do that: "Code that fails to run/compile on a platform doesn't count as a falsey value."

Comment: @Runemoro You're right. However, this is a true value (on windows, the program would end with positive status code; status code is allowed, see the first comment).

Comment: Well, surely you can assemble and  link  it into a valid executable for the platform (ELF or PE) but then you'd have to count either the executable size with all the headers or the source code size.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, No, just like you can run python (with an interpreter), there are programs that run assembly (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448580/interpreting-assembly-code#448610))

Comment: I'm not aware of any such, but even if they exist you still have to count the source code, not raw binary.

Comment: The exit code is set to non-zero, but you get a dialog saying "program.exe has stopped working" first, so I'm not sure if that's ok.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky There are programs that run raw binary too. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Technically, this answer checks for the Linux Kernel (afaics). If I run GNU/Hurd (just like GNU/Linux, but using a different kernel) and compile this program for it, it would say that it was Windows. Equally if I ran this on my x86 smart TV it would say that it was Windows. (Both untested, feel free to prove me wrong!)

Comment: Bochs and QEMU simulate bare metal environment and do not run the binary code under the host OS. So they won't work IMO. But this all could be a discussion for the meta.

Answer (score 9):

## julia, 10 bytes

```
is_windows
```

A function that returns true for windows

Comment: This corresponds to [`Sys.iswindows()` in modern Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/handling-operating-system-variation/)

Answer (score 9):

## C#, <s>61</s> 48 bytes

```
()=>(int)System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform<4
```

Saved 13 bytes thanks to TheLethalCoder

Or a full program at 83 bytes:

```
class P{static int Main(){return(int)System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform<4?1:0;}}
```

Various Windows variants use enum values 0 to 3 in the [Microsoft .NET implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/platformid.cs). 4 is Unix, 5 is Xbox [360] (which I won't consider "Windows"), 6 is MacOSX. [Mono uses the same values](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Detecting_the_execution_platform), adding 128 for Unix/Linux in earlier versions.

Therefore, anything < 4 is Windows, and everything else is not Windows.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but why are you casting the value to an `int`?

Comment: @auhmaan `CS0019 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'PlatformID' and 'int'` -- basically, C#'s typing rules says I can't compare a `PlatformID` and `int` directly, and there's no implicit cast from `PlatformID` to `int`. But there *is* an *explicit* cast from all enums to their values, which I take advantage of here...

Comment: Depends on which xbox you're running this on. XBox ONE runs on Windows 10 therefore correct answer should be returning true.

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88(v=vs.110).aspx), `Xbox` explicitly means "The development platform is Xbox 360.". Also, arguably, by including WinCE I'm already going beyond the scope of the question (which is presumably traditional computers only). IMO, and lacking further clarification from the question author, I will assume "Windows" does not include, say, "Windows Phone".

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ Also, I have to point out that this is targeting C#/.NET Framework/.NET Core. On Xbox One it's only possible to run UWP apps, which use a different API [not including `System.Environment.OSVersion` at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452931). If you're going to take issue with that, then you should also delete every other non-UWP answer. It also turns out that you can't (currently) run UWP apps on non-Windows platforms, so you can go delete all those too. Which leaves you with 0 answers, and an unanswerable question.

Comment: You can compile to an `Action<bool>` in the first example for 48 bytes (I haven't tested it but believe it will work) `_=>(int)System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform<4;` It might need to be `()=>...` for 49 bytes though

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Hm, is that allowed? Without a (implicit or explicit) cast to `Action<bool>`, it's not really a delegate yet... not sure how acceptable that is on PCCG.

Comment: Compiling to anonymous functions such as `Func`s and `Action`s are used all the time here. I believe it's in the golfing tips page and I use them almost all the time. Also anonymous functions are used in other languages a lot so I think it is safe to use them here

Comment: Although if the statement specifies you must write a full-program then obviously `Action`s and `Func`s aren't going to help you. But this challenge just says program and I believe that means you can use an anonymous method (although I may be wrong on that). Though some other answers appear to be using anonymous functions/methods.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ah, ok. Thanks! I do think it needs to be `()=>` because `_=>` takes a param. Also, `Func<bool>` in this case, but apparently that's not part of the function, so... still 48 bytes assuming the semicolon isn't required (it's not part of the anon function, technically).

Comment: I usually include the semi-colon, same as if it was multiline I'd include the braces `{}`. And the challenge doesn't state if you aren't allowed to take input so you could compile to a `Func<int, bool>` and you just don't use the int you pass in. Again still 48 bytes

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript, <del>42</del> <del>30</del> <del>26</del> 25 bytes

```js
console.log((
//Begin
_=>navigator.oscpu[0]>'V'
//End
)())
```

Tested with Firefox. (Chrome doesn't have the `oscpu` property.)
Since lowercase letters have a higher character code than uppercase letters, this depends on the first letter of `navigator.oscpu` being uppercase and not being *W*, *X*, *Y* or *Z* on any platform that Firefox supports (other than Windows, of course). According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9514476/1419007), that is the case.

#### Edits

1. Saved 12 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).
2. Saved another four bytes
3. Saved another byte thanks to [Blender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7800/blender).

Comment: `oscpu` is probably the shortest `navigator` property that you can use. Also, testing a regexp will probably work out shorter, but I haven't measured it.

Comment: You can remove `!=-1` and add a `~` right after the fat arrow, saving 3 bytes.

Comment: Do you have to create a function? Can't you just `console.log` the regex test? Also would `navigator.oscpu[0]=='W'` work or is there another OS that also starts with W.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason my Chrome doesn't have oscpu.

Comment: If it wasn't for `WebTV OS`, I would suggest `navigator.platform[0]=='W'` as a more robust alternative.

Comment: `navigator.oscpu>'V'` might work as well

Comment: `navigator.oscpu>'V'` could produce a false positive on some *nix systems, which derive `navigator.oscpu` from the output of `uname`. [Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname)

Answer (score 7):

### Batch, 50 bytes

```
@if %OS%==Windows_NT if not exist Z:\bin\sh echo 1
```

Edit: Fixed to ignore DOS instead of claiming that it's Windows.

The <s>only</s> other way I know of running Batch outside of Windows is to use WINE which by default will map `Z:` to `/`. Therefore if `Z:\bin\sh` exists, chances are that it's `/bin/sh`, so not MS Windows.

I don't know what WINE sets %OS% to, but if it's not `Windows_NT` then I could save 23 bytes.

Comment: Another way is DOS, which is not Windows.

Comment: Not only does this fail under DOS, but also, on a computer where Z: is mapped, and happens to contain such a path.

Comment: This doesn't work if cygwin is install to the root of drive Z:

Comment: At least I'm _trying_ to detect WINE. None of the other answers will give the correct result when run under WINE either.

Comment: DOS: `set OS=Windows_NT & subst Z: C:\ & mkdir Z:\bin & echo X > Z:\bin\sh`.

Comment: @Adám Sure and if you compile the C answer with -DWIN32=1 then it fails too. Your point?

Comment: yes, wine sets `OS=Windows_NT`

Comment: Doesn't work under MS-DOS 6.22 -- it fails with a syntax error.

Comment: there can be hybrid scripts like [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66695/13151)

Comment: @Mark Strange, it worked for me when I tried it.

Comment: @Neil, are you trying with actual MS-DOS, or with a Windows command prompt?

Comment: @Mark I have an MS-DOS 6.22 VM.

Answer (score 7):

## Node.js, <s>27</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

Thanks to **@Patrick**, who shaved 12 bytes off my solution using Node's REPL:

```
_=>os.EOL>`
`
```

Original solution:

```
_=>require('path').sep!='/'
```

Comment: If you change this to `Node.js REPL`, you can save 16 bytes by just using `_=>path.sep!='/'`

Comment: I'm new to codegolf. Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it. REPL means read, execute, print loop, the program that runs when you enter `node` on the console. From there, all the system node modules are available without the need to `require()` them.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I meant 11. You can save another byte by changing `!=` to `>` since the ASCII index for `\ ` is 92 and `/` is 47.

Answer (score 7):

## Excel VBA, <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>26</s> 24 Bytes

Immediate windows function that returns `true` if the system's OS code starts is longer than length 3, because the info is restricted to output either else `mac` or `pcdos` this returns `true` only on windows pcs

```vba
?[Len(Info("SYSTEM"))>3]
```

**Previous Versions**

```vba
''# Ignore the second `"` that follows every `\` - its only there for highlighting 

?Left(Environ("OS"),1)="W"                 # 24 Bytes

?InStr(ThisWorkbook.Path,"\"")             # 29 Bytes

?Mid(ThisWorkbook.Path,3,1)="\""           # 30 Bytes, Restricted to local Files

?Application.PathSeparator="\""            # 30 Bytes

?Left(Application.OperatingSystem,1)="W"   # 40 Bytes
```

**Changes**

-1 Thanks to Neil for using `Left(...,1)` over `Mid(...,1,1)`

-10 Thanks to ChrisH for pointing out [@Mego's Path Separator Trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106084/44821)

-1 For Checking the `WorkbookPath` for `"\"`  rather than using `Application.Path Separator`

-4 For switching to `Environ()`

-2 For switching to `[Len(Info(...`

**Novel Solution, 51 bytes**

Novel `sub`routine that outputs, to the VBE immediates window, a `1 (truthy)` under windows and `0 (falsey)` under mac by method of conditional compilation.

```vba
Sub a
i=1
#If Mac Then
i=0
#End If
Debug.?i
End Sub
```

Comment: `left` saves you a byte.

Comment: Have you tried it on office365 online? Does that even support VBA? Just curious.

Comment: @ChrisH To my knowledge office.com does not support online VBA scripting (though if anyone else knows better please do tell me, that would make my life significantly easier); However, with O365 you have the rights to download a copy of Office 2016 (or whatever is current) to your desktop, and that does support VBA scripting.

Comment: I've so far manage to avoid it; given your comment that looks set to continue (the only windows machines I use have a desktop copy of office, personal machines are all linux)

Comment: [@Mego's path separator trick](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106084/44821) (`?Application.PathSeparator)="\"` would be 32 as it's a single char)

Answer (score 7):

## QBasic, 31 bytes

```
?INSTR(ENVIRON$("COMSPEC"),"W")
```

Prints non-zero under Windows, 0 under everything else.

`COMSPEC` is an environment variable unique to Microsoft OSs.  It points to the command interpreter, typically `command.com` or `cmd.exe`.  Under Windows, the command interpreter sits somewhere in the Windows directory; under MS-DOS, it sits in the DOS directory or on the root of the disk, and under any other OS, it doesn't exist.

By checking to see if the value of `COMSPEC` contains a "W", we can tell the difference between Windows and not-Windows.

Comment: `COMSPEC` isn't reserved to mean anything in particular under Linux (meaning it's under user control by default), so isn't it possible that the user's set it to a value that they're using for their own purposes (and happens to contain a `W`)? Admittedly, that's a bit of an edge case.

Comment: @ais523: Also, the Windows directory doesn't have to contain a W. It's brittle in either case.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>19</s>  18 bytes

```perl6
put $*DISTRO.is-win
```

```perl6
put ?($*CWD~~/\\/)
```

Both output `True␤` or `False␤` depending on the system it is run on.

Comment: the second one relies on the non windows values of CWD not containing any `\` - there's no guarantee of that,

Answer (score 6):

## bash + coreutils, 5 bytes

```
rm $0
```

Also works in most other POSIXy shells. (Note that Windows ports of `bash` and `rm` exist; even though they're only normally used with more heavily POSIXy operating systems, this isn't an entirely vacuous entry.) Outputs via exit code (0 = false, 1 = true). Can be counted as 4 bytes if you're allowed to assume a filename (e.g. `rm a`). Note that this can potentially fail in the case of very weird filenames (which `rm` will interpret as arguments due to the lack of quoting, and possibly delete files you care about, so I'd advise against running this program from a file with a weird name).

Note: deletes the program from disk as a side effect, or at least tries to. In the case where we're running on Windows, the OS will fail to delete the running file (an operation that Windows disallows either by default or full stop), and thus `rm` will error out. `bash` catches the error and converts it into an exit code (thus the program as a whole terminates normally). Most of the other entries here are using 0 for falsey and 1 for truthy in exit codes, so this does the same; note that `bash`'s `if` statement doesn't accept integers at all (rather, it accepts *commands* and branches based on whether they run successfully, and arithmetic tests are done via the means of programs like `test` that intentionally report a "crash" on a failed comparison), so this is on shakier ground in terms of legality than programs that output via exit code in languages where 0 is valid in an `if` statement test and sends the program to the `else` branch.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
'W'∊∊#⎕WG'APLVersion'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@///v3q4@qOOLiBSftQ3Ndxd3THAJyy1qDgzP08dAA)

`#⎕WG'APLVersion'` Root (**#**) **W**indow **G**et property **APL Version**

`∊` enlist (flatten)

`'W'∊` is **W** a member? (no non-Windows return values contain a capital W)

Answer (score 5):

## [TrumpScript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript), 17 bytes

```
America is great.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KykqzS0oTi7KLCj5/98xN7UoMzlRIbNYIb0oNbFE7/9/AA)

---

This program, if run on windows, will print:

```
The big problem this country has is being PC
```

This is considered a truthy value.

---

Empty output and the following value are falsy:

```
Boycott all Apple products  until such time as Apple gives cellphone info to authorities regarding radical Islamic terrorist couple from Cal
```

The empty output will occur on any linux system (for this program), the long apple response obviously occurs on Mac (for any program). On TIO, the backend (I'm assuming) is a Unix operating system, so you can only get the falsy value; on my computer I get the PC message.

---

Not 100% sure if this counts as an error message (which would invalidate the answer), but if you didn't know about this it was probably worth a laugh for you.

Comment: What has the world come to...

Comment: @avaragecoder MAKE PYTHON GREAT AGAIN!

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>39</s> 31 bytes

```
import System.Info
f=os!!0=='m'
```

I check for the first letter output of "m", which should be "mingw" for windows. As far as I could tell, there is no other OS which starts with M. The information comes from https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/utils/Platform.hs

Comment: On my system (Windows 10 64-bit, GHC 8.0.1 64-bit), `os` gives `"mingw32"`.

Comment: @Mego you are right, corrected for that

Answer (score 4):

## tcl, 38 bytes

```
 expr [lsearch $tcl_platform windows]>0
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 17 Bytes

The following will output 1 if windows and nothing if anything else. Ignoring notices of string convertion.

`<?=PHP_OS==WINNT;`

[Try online](https://3v4l.org/ra15J) Online tests for linux because the sandbox is linux for PoC.

Comment: Sure that is enough? Asking because [Possible Values For: PHP_OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738823/possible-values-for-php-os).

Comment: '<?=PHP_OS[0]==W;` is both 1 byte shorter and catches all the other windows values in the question linked by manatwork. `>V` might work too.

Comment: manatwork depends on which windows version PHP was compiled on, since Windows Visa\7, Windows version has been represented with WINNT because of the NT Authority Kernel.

before windows XP and below was WIN32 and Windows server 2003 was Windows.

Answer (score 4):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 11 bytes

```
 
os 1- not .
```

Prints `true` on Windows, `false` on Linux and macOS. Other platforms supported by 8th are Android, iOS and Raspberry Pi, but I am not able to test on them.

Ungolfed version (with comments)

```
 
G:os  \ Return a number n indicating the operating system 
      \ 0 for Linux
      \ 1 for Windows 
      \ 2 for macOS
      \ 3 for Android 
      \ 4 for iOS 
      \ 5 for Raspberry Pi
n:1-  \ Subtract 1
G:not \ If Windows --> true, otherwise --> false
.     \ Print result
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 49 bytes

```java
()->System.getenv().get("OS").contains("Windows")
```

Longer than the [other Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106092), but takes a different approach.

This lambda fits in a `Supplier<Boolean>` and can be tested with the following program:

```java
public class DetectMSWindows {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(f(() -> System.getenv().get("OS").contains("Windows")));
  }

  private static boolean f(java.util.function.Supplier<Boolean> s) {
    return s.get();
  }

}
```

Comment: It's very, very similar to the initial answer that you link (before the edits).

Comment: Why not just `.contains("W")`?

Comment: @Cyoce actually, the variable OS appears to be Windows-specific.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 (13 bytes)

```
import winreg
```

Returns with exit code zero (generally true in shells) if on windows, and with a non-zero exit code otherwise.

If you prefer it the other way round, there is a 12 bytes solution: `import posix`.

Comment: I think this will not work if there is a file called `winreg.py` in the same directory.

Comment: Also, per the rules: "Code that fails to run/compile on a platform doesn't count as a falsey value."

Answer (score 4):

## Powershell 6, 10 bytes

```
$isWindows
```

`Powershell 6` [intoduce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60) 3 predefined variables: `$isWindows`, `$isLinux` and `$IsMacOs`.

Answer (score 3):

### FPC, 61 chars

```
begin{$ifdef win32}write('f');{$else}write('nf');{$endif}end;
```

Comment: you can shave some bytes by using only one write `begin write({$ifdef win32}1{$else}0{$endif});end.`

Comment: Or to work on win64 as well: `begin write({$ifdef windows}1{$else}0{$endif})end.`

Comment: @hdrz, yes, you right, thanks ;)

Comment: @hdrz, sure that would be correct? 1 and 0 are not truthy/falsey in Pascal. I would go with `begin write(1={$ifdef windows}1{$endif}+0)end.`

Comment: @manatwork, FPC and Delphi supports various types in writeln.
And boolean is can be only 0 or 1 in pascal

Comment: @manatwork - well i'm streching the rules a bit here... anyhow i like your solution much better than mine

Comment: @hdrz, yes, but you left ;.

Comment: You seem to have created a second account with the same name. If that wasn't on purpose, you can follow the steps in [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @Dennis, no, i'm post first and the same answer by unlogged nick.
My first account is monobogdan, but it's blocked by system because haters downvote some posts

Answer (score 3):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula Language, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
@Like(@Platform;"W%")
```

Previous versions:

```
@Left(@Platform;1)="W"
```

or

```
@Begins(@Platform;"W")
```

Computed field formula on a Notes form. @Platform returns 1 of:

```
AIX/64
Linux/64
Macintosh
OS/400®
UNIX
Windows/32
Windows/64
```

So the formula returns 1 (@True) if the platform starts with "W" and 0 (@False) if not.

Answer (score 3):

### Lua, 21 Bytes

```
os.execute"dir c:\\"
```

It will error if not on windows and list the C:\ directory if on windows.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf!

Comment: Debian has a `/bin/dir` that seems almost identical to `/bin/ls`.  If I do `mkdir C:\\` I can fool this script.

Answer (score 3):

## [LibreOffice Calc](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#INFO) / [OpenOffice Calc](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_INFO_function), 21 bytes

**Code:**

```
=INFO("system")="WNT"
```

## [Microsoft Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae), 23 bytes

**Code:**

```
=INFO("system")="pcdos"
```

**Result:**

Returns **TRUE** if Windows; **FALSE** otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), x64 only, 37 bytes

```c
asm("m:_m:.int 50066");f(){m(2,1,0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCsIwFEV3v@IREBKItgp2aCftIA7OjiFNE33DSyRJ6SB@e00Hlwv33sMxu6cxS1XB5E0gsj5DDuBCNBaufb@WKVnILwt3NDGk4DKcLzfQCdABZphttBA8PNCPYU6b4lJK5xxxmLJVinNKSg8oBGCxEy8p4R@ig0Un4oxaRe1@JU513TRMdI6LD/GjPMhadN@FNPqyvGNhHGfbkclCrM8P)

Function called `f()`. Returns `1` for Windows, `0` for non-Windows.

You wanted a "creative solution"? Here you go. Unfortunately, it isn't as short or portable as the other C solution. (TODO: x86, ARM, and ARM64 polyglot /s)

Expanded:

```c
// ASM
// We need both m and _m because macOS uses leading underscores for
// C symbols, while Windows and Linux do not.
m:
_m:
        // We manually encode these in the golfed code to save space.
        // eax = edx
        xchg    eax, edx // 0x92
        ret              // 0xC3
// C
int m(int, int, int);
int f()
{
    // The first parameter can be anything, I use 2 for ease of explanation.
    return m(2, 1, 0);
}
```

What does it do? It uses the fact that Windows and Linux (and Mac, BSD, etc) use different calling conventions on x64.

So, when GCC tries to call `m(2, 1, 0)`, on Windows it will use the Microsoft x64 calling convention (`rcx`, `rdx`, `r8`, `r9`):

```c
    mov     ecx, 2
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     r8d, 0
    call    m
```

However, on Linux, Mac, BSD, etc, it will use the System V calling convention (`rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8`, `r9`):

```c
    mov     edi, 2
    mov     esi, 1
    mov     edx, 0
    call    m
```

As I have bolded, `edx` is used on both platforms, but since they represent different parameters in the calling conventions, Windows and non-Windows will get different values.

With some inline assembly, we can get GCC to return the value of `edx` instead of the third parameter.

To test how it would function on Windows, simply uncomment the prototype at the top, which uses an attribute to force GCC to use the Microsoft ABI.

Comment: I thought Windows was the one that prefixes C symbol names with underscore, or do I mis-remember?

Answer (score 2):

## tcl, 51

```
puts [string match windows $tcl_platform(platform)]
```

I don't have a Windows machine online, but on http://rextester.com/live/OVTY1488 replace `windows` by `unix` to see it output 1 instead of 0.

2nd attempt:

## tcl, 40

```
puts [string match W* $tcl_platform(os)]
```

assuming Windows is the only system the name begins on a W.

3rd attempt:

## tcl, 26

```
puts [info exists env(OS)]
```

assuming Windows is the only system the `OS` environment variable is defined.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 38 bytes

Stealing the [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34881562/1270789):

```
exit (RUBY_PLATFORM=~/(?<!r)win/)!=nil
```

Return 0 on OK, to keep with shell conventions. We need the funny `(?<!r)` negative look-behind to avoid matching `darwin`, although if Microsoft device to make a `vrwin` Windows version for virtual reality the code will fail... On JRuby, though, [this doesn't work so well](https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/386), so instead:

## Ruby including JRuby, 52 bytes

```
exit (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']=~/(?<!r)win/)!=nil
```

I don't have raw Windows, just Cygwin, but if the `host_os` is `windows` then we need to distinguish `nil` and `0`.

## Ruby plus gem install os, 25 (+9?)

This needs an extra gem, so we might have to add an extra 9 bytes for `gem i os` at the command line:

```
require 'os'
exit OS.windows?
```

This also avoids the `darwin` problem completely!

Comment: According to other answer in the question you linked to, your code will reach the conclusion that “darwin” is also “win”. If the question not requires otherwise, by default the answers are expected to be either full programs or functions (or whatever callable entities exist in your language), which should return or output the result explicitly or rely on the interpreter doing it implicitly. As it looks now, your code is a snippet, leaving the generated value in the memory.

Comment: Oops! Filtering out `darwin` makes things lengthier. And let me add an `exit`...

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 18 bytes

```
<?=!(PHP_EOL^'=');
```

### Explanation

`PHP_EOL`, as its name might suggest, returns the line separator on a given system. On Windows, this is CRLF, and on other platforms, this is LF.

`^` is binary XOR. `'='` XOR `"\r"` is `'0'`, and PHP's string bitwise operations truncate to the length of the shortest string, so `"\r\n"` XOR `'='` is also `'0'`.

`!` is boolean NOT. In PHP, `"0"` is considered falsy. So, when we're on Windows, PHP will negate this to `true`. When we're not on Windows, we get a truthy value (`'7'`) which PHP negates to `false`.

`<?=` is the short opening tag for `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby 2, <s>17</s> 14 bytes

17 byte solution: `Gem.win_platform?`
This only works on the newer versions of ruby, as in the older versions you would have to require `rubygems`.

---

#### 14 byte solution:

`system 'del a'` This command outputs true if on windows, because there is a command called `del` in Windows, but outputs `nil` (falsey) on Linux and Mac because there is no such command as `del` in Unix. Oh, and if you are on windows it will delete a file called a in your current directory, that's an unintended side effect :P

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 29 bytes

```
import os;exit(os.name!='nt')
```

Probably should have tryed that first....

### Previous answer (41 bytes)

Two answers I found that are the same size

```
import os;exit(-hasattr(os,"P_DETACH")+1)
```

and

```
import sys;exit(-hasattr(sys,"winver")+1)
```

also -+1 is a neat way to negate the output, gonna keep that one noted

Comment: `-n+1` <-> `1-n`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech true, although I found even more savings by not being fancy :(

Comment: -2 bytes by using `os.name>'o'` (linux and mac is `posix`, while windows is `nt`)

Answer (score 1):

## Elixir, 19 bytes

```
{:win32,_}=:os.type
```

Exit code 0 for Windows, 1 for others.

Answer (score 1):

### Scala, 71 bytes

```
object W extends App{print(sys.env.get("OS").get.contains("Windows"))}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dartlang, 43 bytes

```
import'dart:io';main()=>Platform.isWindows;
```

First answer one here, so I hope this is okay :)

Answer (score 1):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 43 bytes

```d
int f(){version(Windows)return 0;return 1;}
```

D ... is horrible at golfing. But it **does** have a `version` construct, so I thought I'd post an answer in D.

And ... there's really no point in putting a TIO link, since TIO is ran on only one type of OS.

Answer (score 1):

## SQL 2017, 61 bytes

```sql
SELECT IIF(host_platform='Linux',0,1)FROM sys.dm_os_host_info
```

SQL 2017 is the first MS SQL version that can run on a platform other than Windows. The  system view [`sys.dm_os_host_info`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-host-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns either `Linux` or `Windows`, so (at least in this version) anything that isn't on Linux is on Windows.

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 14 bytes

```rust
||!cfg!(unix);
```

The `target_family` attribute is `windows` on Windows and (most) others have `unix`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>26</s> 19 bytes

```
'ª¬7£’ÿ :ï´.ƒª’.E2å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f/dCqQ2vMDy1@1DDz8H4Fq8PrD23ROzbp0CogX8/V6PDS//8B)

```erl
'ª¬7£’...’.E2å  # trimmed program
             å  # is...
            2   # literal...
             å  # in...
          .E    # result of running...
     ’...’      # "ÿ :os.type"...
                # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
    £           # first...
   7            # literal...
    £           # characters of...
'ª¬             # "inspection"...
          .E    # as Elixir code...
             å  # ?
                # implicit output

=================================================

inspect :os.type  # full program
        :os.type  # return tuple of OS family and OS name...
inspect           # as a string
```

`:os.type` return values:

| Family | Names |
| --- | --- |
| `unix` | A result from running `uname -s`. No Unix kernels have `2` in their name, so if the machine is running Unix, the program will return `0`. |
| `win32` | `nt` or `windows` |

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 21 bytes

```
’__£Ø__('ï´').ˆ³’.EÇÈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPM@PhDiw/PiI/XUD@8/tAWdU29022HNgPF9VwPtx/u@P8fAA)

```py
’...’.EÇÈ  # trimmed program
        È  # push 1 minus...
       Ç   # codepoint of...
     .E    # result of running...
’...’      # "__import__('os').sep"...
     .E    # as python code...
        È  # modulo 2
           # implicit output

=================================================

__import__('os').sep  # full program
__import__(    )      # return...
           'os'       # operating system...
                .sep  # file path separator
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 8 bytes

```julia
!is_unix
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@18xszi@NC@z4n9BUWZeiUaahqbmfwA)

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 11 bytes

```julia
!Sys.isunix
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvtfMbiyWC@zuDQvs@J/QVFmXolGmoam5n8A)

Comment: This will give the same value for Windows as macOS.

Comment: i don't have a mac device to test it should give the same output as linux (macOS is unix-based) [see the doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/handling-operating-system-variation/)

Comment: nvm, you're right

Comment: you can save a byte btw by removing the `!` and outputting reversed values (`false` if on windows)

Comment: @Makonede the challenge specifications do not allow that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 11 bytes

```
os windows?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JQXFlckpqrYP0/v1ihPDMvJb@82P6/3n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```
echo defined windows
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/NTkjXyElNS0zLzVFoTwzLyW/vPj/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua (LuaJIT)](https://luajit.org/), 17 bytes

```lua
print(jit.os>"V")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN1M0pTczKLPn/v6AoM69EA8jUyy@2UwpT0vz/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
‘\_\_Ʋ¡\_\_('Ỵġ').ẓ÷()‘E`ż³=
```

Uses `platform.system()`, as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857/18746959).

##### Explanation

```python
‘...‘E`ż³=  # Full program
‘...‘       # Push compressed string "__import__('platform').system()"
     E      # Evaluate as Python code (returns "Linux"/"Darwin"/"Windows")
      `ż³   # Push compressed string "Windows"
         =  # Are they equal?
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <s>33</s> 39 bytes

```swift
var f={#if os(Windows)
1#else
0#endif
}
```

Simply performs a compile-time check on the OS family and returns `1` if it's on Windows, or `0` otherwise. (I'm not gonna lie, I'm a little surprised you can put compiler directives on non-new lines like that...)

Comment: Does this actually output or just assign to a variable? Just assigning is not a valid output format

Comment: @mousetail You’re right, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, <s>26</s> 17 bytes

Shameless plug for the TCL answer I saw that used the OS environment variable.

```rkt
(and(getenv"OS"))
```

---

(Old answer)

Pretty straight forward. `system-type` with no argument returns a symbol indicating the system operating system type.

```rkt
(eq?'windows(system-type))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nim, 37 bytes**

```
quit when defined(windows): 0 else: 1
```

Returns exit code `0` for Windows, `1` for all other operating systems. Uses conditional compilation with `when`.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 17

```
gdr|? P* -like *y
```

Abusing the fact that there's no Registry PSProvider on non-Windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

## Node.js, 23 bytes

```
_=>os.platform=="win32"
```

Comment: This only appears to be a snippet, as opposed to [a full program or a function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422).

Answer (score 0):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>45</s> 37 bytes

```
BEGIN{print PROCINFO["platform"]~/w/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9PS8NAEMXv@RRDvKZZwZM9WrQUTCvWtoL0MKabzdL9E7KbboroV4@TaKgHB3Z5w/B@8wbDsevu7ueL5UdVS@Ph6Xk1WywfVm9xpdAXttbx/osF9tl1pfeVmzIWQkiFaVJbC@Zs4QPWnAkMR6bRNKgGnZZeqytpDrydjKRJ3RgjjZhYE0X/LYoioHoppQOuuOaUR8gTd4DgPMUTQECZo@@lLzmMVqAPQinzciD0ASCgg9zqSip@SAnK4YSq4RCkUvDOwRp6xYAprFI2EHT6kyDWpEM86L4ymde2PxV2FMAGl0Dj@gyZNPNd@muy7ub2@mJarRn147CyTraX4Xy5YY/SNG0Cs7Og1QlkmJMHXhNAcwDFBeZn2BjZgjs7z7UbUSft/mypuNlma6D7t9gykuk3)

Evaluates the `PROCINFO["platform"]` built-in variable, and returns `1` if it matches any `w` character; returns `0` otherwise. Why, you ask? According to the [GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-platform-running-on), only `mingw` option has a letter `w`:

```
PROCINFO["platform"]

    This element gives a string indicating the platform for which
    gawk was compiled. The value will be one of the following:

    "mingw"
        Microsoft Windows, using MinGW.

    "os390"
        OS/390.

    "posix"
        GNU/Linux, Cygwin, Mac OS X, and legacy Unix systems.

    "vms"
        OpenVMS or Vax/VMS.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 78 bytes

Raises a `KeyError` exception if it can't determine if running on Windows. On not-Windows it can return either None or 0 (both are falsy), on Windows it returns 1.

```py
def f():
 try:open(':','x')
 except Exception as e:return{17:0,22:1}[e.errno]
```

`:` is a forbidden character on Windows (also on DOS, etc.)

Comment: The colon is also an invalid character in file names on macOS, so this seems like it would produce a lot of false-positives, if the goal is to detect Windows. In fact, it specifically violates the rules of the challenge, which was to fail to detect OS X. Have you actually verified that this does not result in an error on macOS?

Comment: @CodyGray I remember having tested this on my Hackintosh, but I'll check again just in case.

Comment: It does actually work on Mac OS Sierra (10.12).

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 18 bytes

```powershell
$env:OS-like"Win*"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyU1r8zKP1g3JzM7VSk8M09L6f9/AA)